# How to change from -source 1.6 to -source 7 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I' trying to build a in IntelliJ IDEA project that is not mine and I got the following error:

*java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)*

How do I change this setting in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S (Project Structure icon)

Then change Project language level

Comment: Just to highlight a point made in an answer below, use Command+; on Mac

Comment: Project language level isn't enough, you have to change your module level, see Kesri and Allen answers.

Comment: IntelliJ is great, but what's not so great is I have to rely on Stackoverflow in 2023 to figure this out.

Answer (score 25):

I know the OP uses IntelliJ IDEA, but Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA, so I wanna say one more word.

If you use Android Studio, `command+;`(for Mac) or `File->Project Structure`, then in the open window follow the settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you I was looking everywhere for this setting.

Answer (score 22):

And, if you're working with a maven project, for sanity, remember to set the java version in the pom too.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 17):

File -> Project Structure -> Sources -> Language level

You will have to reload IDEA

Answer (score 10):

`File->Project structure->Project Settings->Modules->Language level`

Change level using drop down.

Otherwise,
If you are using maven for build,

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 6):

For me, changing the Language Level in Project Structure and restarting IDEA didn't help.

I had to edit the `build.gradle` in `core` module and change the source compatibility from 1.6 to 1.7:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.7 //changed from 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

Build -> Clean Project

Answer (score 1):

For me, above answers didn't work, although they helped me solve my issue. At module level `build.gradle` do the following:

```
compileOptions {
        // I've changed below values from VERSION_1_6 to VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```