# java spring project doesnt read all dependencies

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

i have work with Intellij a java spring project

these error appear to me when i build and run the project :

> cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'
>
> Error:(32, 48) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
>     (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
>
> Error:(33, 55) java: method references are not supported in -source 1.5
>     (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)

i have search about similar question but not working with me

i have try:

invalidate cache and re import to maven dependencies but still gave and error

my java version: javac 1.8.0_111

[image]

maven error:

[image]

and upload the error log file to [drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sGWcEwXXQm_6rbLAQj7hCLNcMWEVkKmQ)

Comment: Add the following properties to maven   `<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>  
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>`

Comment: Have you try to "Reimport All Maven Projects" and "Generate sources and Update Folders For All Projects"? Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea

Comment: yes i have tried these solution but that doesn't fix the problem, i will look at the link that you give me

Comment: after following the link , maven gave me this error :

Comment: failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring -boot-starter-parent:pom2.0.0.RELESE
from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot was caches in the local repository, resolution
will not reattemnpted until the update interval of spring-snapshots has elapsed
or update are forced. original error: could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring -boot-starter-parent:pom2.0.0.RELESE
from/to spring-snapshots ( https://repo.spring.io/snapshot ) : PXIX path building failed
sun.security.provider.certpath.sunCertPathBuildException:unable to find valid certification

Comment: i have update the question post with :
1 - maven error
2 - error log file

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531377/how-to-change-from-source-1-6-to-source-7-in-intellij-idea

Comment: The error is saying your source level is java 1.5

Comment: yes i have tried to edit it, but there are no choice to select 1.8 , and its wrong to write it my self, so how can i change to 1.8 if there are no choice to select it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem with Maven. Either update or add maven-compiler-plugin plugin in your pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>//version_number</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build
```

Comment: nothing change ... still not working ,
i have try re-importing to maven and have an error :
i have update the question post with :
1 - maven error
2 - error log file

Comment: in the error log there's one error of 'parent-path' pointing at no local pom. can you check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450720/mavennon-resolvable-parent-pom-and-parent-relativepath-points-at-wrong-local]

Comment: i have done the update in your link and nothing change ... but after checking jdk path and in dependencies and language level, just this error appear 'Error: java: javac release 8 require target release 1.8 ' but i have in setting 1.5 and there are no choice to  chose 1.8 and when i write it my self the project crush

Answer (score 0):

In project structure, under Modules inside Dependencies, Module SDK should be mapped to your java 8.